# How to format the Level column value in Serilog’s MS Sql Server Sink

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

I am trying to use Serilog in my .Net Core API to log to SQL Server with the [Serilog-Sinks-MSSqlServer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver) sink. The standard `Level` column either writes out the full value (e.g. Information, Warning, Error) or a `TinyInt` enum value if you set the `StoreAsEnum` property to true as shown [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration). I cannot seem to find an easy way (like there is in Log4net and NLog) to format the output to write only the first character of the Level (e.g. I, W, E). I tried setting the `DataLength` property to 1 but that causes the log entry to not be written at all.

I have been able to accomplish my desired behavior with a custom enricher that takes the `Level` value from the standard column and then uses just the first character to write to a custom column while removing the standard `Level` column but that really seems like overkill when I feel like there may be a formatting mechanism somewhere that I just haven’t seen.

Answer (score 0):

For [Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver#json-microsoftextensionsconfiguration), it does not expose easy way to custom the `Level` value.

If you check [MSSqlServerSink](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/MSSqlServerSink.cs#L82), you will see that it convert `IEnumerable<LogEvent> events` to `_traits.eventTable` by a private method, which means you could not override the method `void FillDataTable(IEnumerable<LogEvent> events)`.

In addition, for [MSSqlServerSinkTraits](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/MSSqlServerSinkTraits.cs#L28), it is `internal`, you could not inherit from it to implement your own `MSSqlServerSinkTrait`.

There is no much thing you could not if you want to override something from `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer`.

For easiest way, you may consider forking the `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer`, and change [GetStandardColumnNameAndValue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-mssqlserver/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer/Sinks/MSSqlServer/MSSqlServerSinkTraits.cs#L112) from below code

```
case StandardColumn.Level:
    return new KeyValuePair<string, object>(columnOptions.Level.ColumnName, columnOptions.Level.StoreAsEnum ? (object)logEvent.Level : logEvent.Level.ToString());
```

to change `logEvent.Level.ToString()` to your expected value like `logEvent.Level.ToString().Substring(0,1)`.

Then build the project and reference this project instead of `Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer`